# Replacing list item based on another list using pseudo-token

Tags: python, replace, token

So, I am new to Python. I want to replace the values of my list if they are also in another list and change them to a specified value, pseudo token (OOV). I have turned them into tokens and with a regex i cleaned the code a little bit. 
This is my code:

```
def replace_words(list1, list2):
  for word in list1:
    for words in list2:
     if word == words:
        word = "OOV"




replace_words(list1, list2)
list1.count("OOV") #this keeps showing 0, so something is wrong...
```

Comment: What are your list1 and list2?

Comment: It would help greatly here to have example inputs to be able to actually reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working beacuse you are trying to assign the variable `word` a new value `OOV` which is fine but it doesn't actually changes that element inside the `list1`. So you need to change item **inplace** inside `list1`

**Try this:**

```
def replace_words(list1, list2):
  for idx in range(len(list1)):
      if list1[idx] in list2:
          list1[idx] = "OOV"
```

And when you now execute `>>>list1.count("OOV")` it will not return 0 if there is value in `list1` which is also in `list2`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @KatGl if this answers your question you can accept the answer as correct answer to mark the question completed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is assuming that setting `word = "oov"` will replace the element in the list. This is not true you need to replace by accessing the index of that list. Read more on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)

The following should work

```py
def replace_words(list1, list2):
  for i in range(0,len(list1)-1):#using index
    for words in list2:
     if list1[i] == words:
        list1[i] = "OOV"

replace_words(list1, list2)
list1.count("OOV")
```